# IPython notebook how to restart the kernel, using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to restart IPython (jupiter) notebook Kernel and clear all outputs. The keyboard shortcut is `O,O`. But when I try `ESC + O + O`, nothing happens. Am I missing something? The interrupt kernel, however, shortcut `I,I` works.

Comment: Are you trying the letter `O` instead of the number `0`? Think of resetting the kernel to zero variables.

Comment: I see. Thanks. It looks like O rather than 0(zero)

Answer (score 6):

The keyboard shortcut is `ESC`, `0`, `0` as Thomas indicated (i.e. zeros, *not* the letter `O`).